# Many rows vs JSON for a capped number of entries/rows per user

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a list of events tied to each user ID.

```
user_id BIGINTEGER
event_type STRING
created_at TIMESTAMP
# Some other data columns
```

At any given moment, we want to keep track of the most recent 200 events per user.  Anything beyond that horizon is pointless.

There's two solutions I've thought of that each have questions/issues:

1. Have a table which stores (user_id, event_type, created_at, ...) rows.  Upon updating a user's data, we could run a query that finds the timestamp up to the 200th event, and use that value to delete any older rows for that user.

```
DELETE 
FROM user_events 
WHERE user_id = :userId AND created_at < (
    SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM (
        SELECT created_at 
        FROM user_events
        WHERE user_id = :userIdAgain 
        ORDER BY created_at DESC 
        LIMIT 200
    ) as user_recent_events
)
```

2. In the user table, have something like (user_id, event_data, ...), where event_data is a JSON column with all the events.

The problem with #2 seems to be that unless the user is retrieved from the database (so that event data can be populated) prior to being updated, we may overwrite the event log, which is not good.

The problem with #1 is that I'm concerned about the potential cost of deletes if there are very many rows.  While at any given time there is unlikely to be more than ~100 rows deleted per user update worst case (typically more like 0-20), there are in the range of 1-10m users, and therefore 200m-2b rows.

I'm leaning towards #1 right now just because the asynchronous nature of the system makes the risk of data loss in #2 worrisome to me, but I'm not sure if my solution is a good one.

Comments?

### Edit -

I should note that user_events has a primary key on user_id, event_type, and a number of data columns.  This is because events can be replayed, but I only want to log the first occurrence.  The total size of this key is ~130 bytes.

Comment: If you run the delete query whenever you're adding a new event, it will only delete one row at a time. There will never be more than 200 rows per user, it just deletes the oldest row when it adds a new one.

Comment: Ah true, I'd have to make sure it selects nothing if there's less than 200...

Comment: If there's less than 200, there won't be any rows that have a date < the minimum row.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this in a trigger, since a trigger isn't allowed to modify the same table.

Comment: Well I was thinking I could do a LIMIT 1 OFFSET 200, but from what you say, it looks like the DELETE query would work as expected.  The reason I mentioned many rows can be deleted at once is because more than one row can be inserted at once.

Currently, a process may insert a batch of 100 new events for example, after which the DELETE is executed.  I figure it might not make sense to interleave a DELETE after every single INSERT given that multiple inserts may be happening.

Comment: No, it would be better to do all 100 deletes at once.

Comment: Yep, that's why I'm calling the DELETE only after all INSERTs are done.  Just concerned whether deleting so regularly will cause issues given the size and number of rows expected.  It would seem to avoid the risk of one process overwriting another process.

Comment: You might need to periodically OPTIMIZE TABLE, but otherwise I think it should be fine.

Comment: Ha, I didn't know OPTIMIZE TABLE existed, thanks!  Well, total user insert/update throughput (and therefore deletes) would be no higher than ~500/s, so I think that might tend towards your instinct of it being fine.  Do you have an estimate of when it might become "not fine" to approach the problem this way?  Or would I likely hit the need to partition before such an issue would occur?